# In Transformers, for the maximum length of Encoder's input sequences and Decoder's input sequences - should they be two different numbers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, transformers, seq2seq

I noticed that there's usually a [limit for the input length](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/520148/what-is-the-length-limit-of-transformers) of transformers. But considering there are actually two input layers - one for the Encoders and one for the Decoders, **can we** and **should we** have two separate `MAX_TOKENS` for them?

If we have different `MAX_TOKENS` for Encoder  input and Decoder input, then the cross attention matrix would be not a square matrix anymore. However in my opnion there are practical reasons to do so, for example, in machine translation we have a source language sentence and target language sentence, which highly likely have different lengths.

English: *I like weightlifting*. ------------------ 3 tokens
Chinese: *我　喜　欢　举　重*。----------- 5 tokens

But from TensorFlow's Tutorial on Transformers ([Neural machine translation with a Transformer and Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer#set_up_a_data_pipeline_with_tfdata)), the source sequence and target sequence are trimmed to the same length `MAX_TOKENS`:

```py
    MAX_TOKENS=128
    def prepare_batch(pt, en):
        pt = tokenizers.pt.tokenize(pt)      # Output is ragged.
        pt = pt[:, :MAX_TOKENS]    # Trim to MAX_TOKENS.
        pt = pt.to_tensor()  # Convert to 0-padded dense Tensor
    
        en = tokenizers.en.tokenize(en)
        en = en[:, :(MAX_TOKENS+1)]
        en_inputs = en[:, :-1].to_tensor()  # Drop the [END] tokens
        en_labels = en[:, 1:].to_tensor()   # Drop the [START] tokens
    
        return (pt, en_inputs), en_labels
```

Is this just for the sake of simplicity, or it is a norm to use a unified `MAX_TOKENS` for both Encoder input and Decoder input?

In a practical application, what is the best way to determine the value of `MAX_TOKENS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [tutorial you refer to](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer), the only reason is simplicity. However, in machine translation practice, there is typically no reason to use different maximum lengths.

Transformers often use learned position embeddings (instead of the sinusoidal position encoding in the original [Transformer paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2017/file/3f5ee243547dee91fbd053c1c4a845aa-Paper.pdf)). In that case, limiting the source or target side more would mean less training signal for the position embeddings. Also, due to [byte-pair encoding](https://aclanthology.org/P16-1162/) and similar algorithms used for input text segmentation, the length of the source and target sentences are typically similar, even for languages that typically use a different number of words to express the same thing.

Comment: So, in summary, theoratically/programmingly we can use different `max_length` for encoder input and decoder input respectively, but this does not bring any benefits? 

In the transformer tutorial I mentioned, the author has made a plot for both English (Decoder side) and Portugese (Encoder side) sentence lengths after tokenization, and from the plot he determined the "max length" by skipping some "outliers" of the length values.

Actually I am considering non-NLP scenarios for Transformer model, therefore I will not need the tokenization or text segmentation. I'll use entity IDs directly.